# Using re.match in an If statement in Python

Tags: python, regex, function, if-statement

I am setting up a function in Python to receive a date in the format MM/DD/YYYY, then validate it with a regular expression. This is what I have right now:

```
def getdate():
    date = raw_input("Please enter the date completed (MM/DD/YYY): ")
    if re.match(r"\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}", date)
        break
    else:
        print "Incorrect date format"
        getdate()
```

The system keeps returning a syntax error pointing at the close parentheses in the "if" line. I can't seem to figure out exactly what it is considering a syntax error. I have also tried this with no success:

```
def getdate():
    date = raw_input("Please enter the date completed (MM/DD/YYY): ")
    valid = "(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})"
    if re.match(valid, date)
        break
    else:
        print "Incorrect date format"
        getdate()
```

This also returns the same error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a colon at the end:

```
if re.match(r"\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}", date):
#                               here --^
```

Python uses colons to end statements.

Also, as @RohitJain stated, using recursion to ask for repeated input is bad practice.  You might want to make your code like this:

```
def getdate():
    date = raw_input("Please enter the date completed (MM/DD/YYY): ")
    valid = "(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})"
    while not re.match(valid, date):
        print "Incorrect date format"
        date = raw_input("Please enter the date completed (MM/DD/YYY): ")
    return date
```

This new code uses a loop that runs until the input meets the specifications (namely, `re.match` returns with a match).

Comment: Oh thank you very much for the suggestion! Using a while loop vice an if statement is genius!

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the colon:

```
if re.match(r"\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}", date):  # <-- colon needs to be here
```

**P.S:** Please don't use recursion to ask for repetitive inputs. You might end up blowing the stack. Better use a loop. Also, devise some way to allow users only a certain number of attempts, to avoid the infinite loop.

Comment: I cannot believe I missed that.... That is embarrassing. Thank you. It never fails to have someone else look at your code... Thanks for the suggestion too. I see what you mean. I will fix that.